# Metodo Old en Form::text

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

Cómo puedo poner el método old en el Form:text para que se quede lo que escribieron y no se borre?

```
{!!Form::text('titulo',Input::old('titulo'),array('class'=>'form-control'))!!}
```

> Error:
>   Class 'Input' not found

Comment: ¿Es esto una pregunta de Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza el helper old() en vez de llamar a la clase Input:

```
{!!  Form::text('titulo', old('titulo'), ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Revisa la documentación de los helpers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-old